# How to make an Autocomplete. textbox in cakephp2

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, autocomplete

Honestly I know this question has been asked several times but have not seen any that works for me. please help a brother. Pls Help me with code that worked for you including version of the particular jqueryui used

Comment: I tried implementing this www.blogfreakz.com/cakephp/cakephp-jquery-autocomplete-tutorial/
No error just Didn't work. Looks like d problem is with (if($this->requestHandler->isAjax()) nothing works in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

I used a little something like this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="grain" name="grain">
<script>$(function(){
    var available_grain = [
       <?php
          foreach($grain as $item) {
             echo '"' . $item['grain'] . '"';
             if($item !== end($grain))
             echo ',';
          }
        ?>
    ];

   $("#grain").autocomplete({
      source: available_grain
    });
});
</script>
```

Where I had my controller serving up an array $grain that contained all of my autocomplete options. Then I called it with:

```
 $field = $this->autocomplete('grain');
```

Using jQuery UI 1.12, for what it's worth.

Comment: Mr Micheal pls can u help me with d code in ur controller

Comment: How does your php page get the data to fill out the autocomplete?